# python : convert 24 hours and why use if will return None

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def time24hr(tstr): 
    if tstr[-2:0] == 'am' and tstr[0:2] == '12':
        a = '00' + tstr[3:5] + 'hr'
        return a

    elif tstr[-2:0] == 'am' and tstr[0:2] != '12':
        b = tstr[0:2] + tstr[3:5] + 'hr'
        return b
    elif tstr[-2:0] == 'pm':
        c = str(int(tstr[0:2]) + 12) + tstr[3:5] + 'hr'
        return c
```

I'm confused about why this function does not return strings, but show return None

Comment: What if none of your `if` conditions is met?

Comment: By the way, `tstr[-2:0]` is empty, because you're specifying an end point less than the start point. You mean `tstr[-2:]`. Or use [`endswith`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith).

Comment: How does your input `tstr` look like?

Answer (score 1):

You have `if`..`elif`..`elif`, which means that if input `tstr` doesn't satisfy any of the conditions your function will return None, since there are **no return statement outside of if or elif block**.

Answer (score 0):

If the conditions are not satisfied it returns None (because there is no return value in that case).

You can add a return value if all the conditions are not satisfied (i.e. `false`).
This tell that the `tstr` you provided is not a well formatted time to be transformed within your function.

```
 def time24hr(tstr): 
    if tstr[-2:0] == 'am' and tstr[0:2] == '12':
        a = '00' + tstr[3:5] + 'hr'
        return a

    elif tstr[-2:0] == 'am' and tstr[0:2] != '12':
        b = tstr[0:2] + tstr[3:5] + 'hr'
        return b
    elif tstr[-2:0] == 'pm':
        c = str(int(tstr[0:2]) + 12) + tstr[3:5] + 'hr'
        return c
    return false
```

Answer (score 0):

The below changes on your if conditions would help solve your issue. I just converted `tstr[-2:0]` to `tstr[-2:]`

```
def time24hr(tstr): 
if tstr[-2:] == 'am' and tstr[0:2] == '12':
    a = '00' + tstr[3:5] + 'hr'
    return a
elif tstr[-2:] == 'am' and tstr[0:2] != '12':
    b = tstr[0:2] + tstr[3:5] + 'hr'
    return b
elif tstr[-2:] == 'pm':
    c = str(int(tstr[0:2]) + 12) + tstr[3:5] + 'hr'
    return c
```

Hope it helps.